# How to parse a stored procedure signature in C# from plain text

Tags: c#, sql, regex, parsing, stored-procedures

I have a `.sql` file with stored procedures definitions.

I need to write a small program in C# that reads the file and obtains a list with the stored procedures signatures.

For example, this list should look like this:

```
[dbo].[procedureOne] ( int, int, varchar(250) out, nvarchar) 
[dbo].[procedureTwo] ( int, varchar(255) )
[dbo].[procedureThree] (  ) 
[dbo].[amazingSP] ( datetime, datetime )
```

Is there a way to do this using Regex?

What is the best approach?

Comment: what is the structure of the input?

Comment: the input is a .sql file, with stored procedures definitions like "CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[amazingSP] param1 int, param2 datetime... etc"

Comment: So the file doesn't have any extra information like schema stuff, just a straight CREATE PROC ...

Comment: No, the file is a sql full of DDL and DML statements of any kind. The idea is to try to find the statements that are stored procedures and parse their signature. There file could contain almost anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, i implemented by hand a signature parser in C#. It took me some days to polish it, because there always were some cases which broke the parser causing unexpected results.
It was fun coding it anyway.
I'll upload the code when i have it finished if someone needs it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do it with Regex, but I think writing a parser would be actually be easier in this case.

If you want, you can try out [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/), which is very simple to use.